# How to handle an InterruptedException

Tags: java, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handling InterruptedException in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976344/handling-interruptedexception-in-java)

I wonder how `InterruptedException` should be properly handled. What actions should be performed in catch block? Are there any circumstances when the exception should be delegated to the higher level class?

Comment: Unfortunately the answer to this question is "it depends". You should go off and read [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html) and see if it helps you. It is an excellent treatment of the issues around InterruptedException.

Comment: http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of InterruptedException is to allow a blocking method to cancel early, when requested. The one thing you shouldn't do is nothing; don't just swallow the exception.

If you can't throw the exception from your method, calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` is usually a good bet.

Check out Brian Goetz's article, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html, for a good discussion on this topic. Edit: looks like somebody suggested this article already - in any case, it's a good read.