# Check scheduled tasks status

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I have an application that uses a `ScheduledExecutorService` to handle multiple `Runnable`: each one is scheduled at fixed rate and **must** be alive as long as the application.

I need a solution to be notified if any of those threads is terminated for some exception, so I can schedule them again.

Can I use any pattern for this problem? Or am I using the wrong objects in my application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442322/scheduledexecutorservice-check-if-scheduled-task-has-already-been-completed

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier if you simply wrap the `Runnable` so that exceptions never cause the task to be cancelled:

```
class CatchingRunnable implements Runnable {
  private final Runnable delegate;

  CatchingRunnable(Runnable delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  @Override public void run() {
    try {
      delegate.run();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      // Handle the exception somehow, e.g. log it.
    }
  }
}
```

Now schedule `runnable` via:

```
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new CatchingRunnable(runnable), delay, period, unit);
```

Then you never need to worry about rescheduling them.

Comment: This is good, but it might be difficult to predict any kind of exception you can have and handle it accordingly. Suggestion: from the ```catch``` block, call back to the class that has the executor, and reschedule. To do that, you will probably have another interface instead of ```Runnable``` for ```delegate```, that also has a function (e.g. ```recreate()```) to recreate the same delegate.

Comment: @JornVernee well, sure, you might want to handle specific exceptions in specific ways. But 1) how would you handle those "unknowable" exceptions by some other means? 2) If your goal is "if it failed, restart it", the type of the exception doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, my point was number 2, the type of exception doesn't matter. The suggestion was to have the runnable reschedule itself if it terminates with an exception. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

You alternatively could maintain a handler to resubmit if the ScheduleFuture completes.