# Prevent the cron execution, if it is already running

Tags: java, cron, scheduler

I have a(or many) cron task, and it executed every 5s(this is not matter), and i want it will not execute if the previous running is unfinished.
Here is my code: and if the scheduler execute first time at 12:00:00, I  want it executed after 12:00:10 for the second(third ...) times. Can anyone help me ?

```
public class Task {
    private Long id;
    private String cron;
    private Long millis; //the task runnig time(begin to end)

    //getter setter
}

public class TaskSchedulerTest {
    private Map<Long, ScheduledFuture> futureMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TaskSchedulerTest().t();
    }

    private void t() {
        Task t1 = new Task(1L, "0/3 * * * * *", 10000L);
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.initialize();
        taskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("scheduler task");
        ScheduledFuture sf1 = taskScheduler.schedule(new RunnableTask(t1), new CronTrigger(t1.getCron()));
        futureMap.put(t1.getId(), sf1);
    }

    private class RunnableTask implements Runnable {
        private Task task;
        private int times;

        private RunnableTask() {
        }

        private void println(String string) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + string);
        }

        private RunnableTask(Task task) {
            this.task = task;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //check if previous is not finished, i checked it's isDone()
            //and it return false while the previous is running
            println(" begin: " + task.getId() + " times: " + times);
            ScheduledFuture future = futureMap.get(task.getId());
            println(" done: " + future.isDone());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(task.getMillis()); //or do something
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            println(" end: " + task.getId() + " times: " + times);
            times++;
        }
    }
}
```

I use new cron "0/3 * * * * *" and replace sleep to read and write file, like this:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\test\\test.exe");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\test\\a-" + times + "");
fos.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(fis));
fos.flush();
fos.close();
fis.close();
```

And this is the log:

> scheduler task1 begin: 1 times: 0 timestamp:05:51
>
> scheduler task1 end: 1 times: 0 timestamp:06:10
>
> scheduler task1 begin: 1 times: 1 timestamp:06:11
>
> scheduler task1 end: 1 times: 1 timestamp:06:17
>
> scheduler task2 begin: 1 times: 2 timestamp:06:18
>
> scheduler task2 end: 1 times: 2 timestamp:06:24
>
> scheduler task1 begin: 1 times: 3 timestamp:06:25
>
> scheduler task1 end: 1 times: 3 timestamp:06:33
>
> scheduler task3 begin: 1 times: 4 timestamp:06:34
>
> scheduler task3 end: 1 times: 4 timestamp:06:40

The log mean my problem is not a problem.

Comment: Have a lock id and store in some shared server preferrably redis and start another task only of id is not present.

Comment: I can not use redis, because the appplication my be restarted, use redis or other server, It may not be execute again.

Comment: A similar one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442322/scheduledexecutorservice-check-if-scheduled-task-has-already-been-completed

Comment: It is not my expected, and i fount my problem does not exists.
see the description.