# interrupted status after InterruptedException is thrown in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

```
try{...}
catch(InterruptedException e)
{  }
```

I wonder what happen after InterruptedException  is thrown

is thread  interrupted status set to true or not ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling InterruptedException in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976344/handling-interruptedexception-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what throws the InterruptedException. But the good practice, followed by methods of the JDK, is to clear the interrupt status when the exception is thrown.

See [Object.wait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) for example:

> if any thread interrupted the current thread before or while the current thread was waiting for a notification. The interrupted status of the current thread is cleared when this exception is thrown.

Comment: All JDK methods that throw `InterruptedException` that I know of behave the same as `Object.wait()`.  i.e. The interrupt bit is cleared when the exception is thrown.  That's why we need to re-interrupt the thread in the catch.

Comment: @Gray: what I wanted to point out is that you're free to throw the exception yourself, but it doesn't automatically clear the interrupt status. The JDK methods consistently clear it before throwing the exception.

Comment: I figured @JB.  I just wanted to more specific about it.