# Cancel function in a java ThreadPool - Detect specific runnable in the Pool and cancel it

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I have a ThreadPool in my android application where I run a bunch of threads in different situation in it.

```
public class ThreadPoolExecuter {

    private final ExecutorService mExecuter;
    private static final int nThreads = 5;

    private ThreadPoolExecuter() { 
        this.mExecuter = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
    }
```

Java ThreadPool have no default to cancel thread. One solution that I thought about was keeping a key-value pairs of Future when I submit runnable.

```
public void add(Runnable runnable) {
    Future<?> future = this.mExecuter.submit(runnable);
    // Add future to my key-value pairs
    if(Constant.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Task submitted.");
}
```

And then have a cancel function:

```
public boolean cancel(KEY) {
   Future<?> future = map.get(KEY)
   return future.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
}
```

Let's say a HashMap. The value is the Future, what about key? 1)What is your suggestion?

```
Map<Key, Future<?>> map = new HashMap()<key, Future<?>>;
```

About the key I thought about passing an id for every runnable as follows:

2)what do you think about this solution?

But I would mention that in my runnable class sometimes I faced with InterruptedException. Is there any way to avoid it?

```
class Runner implements Runnable {

    private int id;

    public Runner(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Starting " + id);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Crashed on:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
        System.out.println("ending " + id);
    }
}
```

3 ) At the end I want to add it is important for me to know any better solution in your point of view to develop a cancel function in java ThreadPool?

Notice that I don't look for a replacement for my ThreadPool such as AsyncTask in Android which has default cancellation.

Comment: Why do you want to have `KEY` instead of having the actual `Future`?

Comment: There could be a bunch of threads running in the Pool. `this.mExecuter = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);` I want to detect one of them and cancel that specific one, while others are running normally.

Comment: This is what is `Future` instance for, you don't have to add another level on indirection unless you need to expose it outside of the JVM.

Comment: Ok, so maybe I can keep a list of Future (List<Future<?>>) in my ThreadPool class. Sometimes I faced with InterruptedException, do you know how can I avoid it? (it is just sometimes)

Comment: Why do you want to keep the list? Do you at some point need to cancel all the tasks at once? On how to handle `InterrputedException` see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976344/handling-interruptedexception-in-java

Comment: Yes maybe the only point to keep a list is to cancel all the tasks at once. But maybe `shutdownNow` is a better option. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Definitely `shutdownNow` with the properly handled `InterrputedException`s is the way to go.

Comment: @pingw33n, you can share your answer, so I can mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your primary need is to be able to cancel all running tasks at once you should be able to use `shutdownNow()` of the `ExecutorService`. Default `ExecutorService` implementations will call `Thread.interrupt()` in order to abort the running threads so you should handle `InterrputedException` properly (by closing any resources used and exiting the thread).

Answer (score 0):

Generally cancelling threads from outside the thread itself contains all sorts of risks that aren't obvious at first. A safer approach is to have the thread when it starts check to see whether it still needs to run.