# Java threads and thread interrupts

Tags: java, multithreading

From all the resources I could pull together, I still cannot grasp thread interrupts.. From Oracle's own tutorials (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html), they don't explain what causes the interrupt exception to be thrown, or how, or what it even is.. they just say it can happen whenever you invoke certain methods like Thread.sleep(). Does it randomly happen when it's called? Is there a length of time that it takes for the exception to be thrown? Is it thrown every time it's called? None of that makes sense because if it's random, it'd be useless to a programmer, and if it happens every time a certain method is called, it'd have no real use.. they explain very little about it, and just move on to other thread concepts.. I haven't had any issues with learning C, Lua, or Python, because the tutorials and documentation provided by them actually explains everything, this is the first time I've ever been completely stumped by a tutorial. I've been searching for about 2 hours for an answer.

Can you include what InterruptedException is exactly, and WHY it's thrown?

Comment: The class `Thread` has an `interrupt` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the first paragraph of the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) you link to:

> A thread sends an interrupt by invoking `interrupt` on the `Thread` object
>   for the thread to be interrupted.

This means interruption of `Thread threadX` is caused by any other thread calling `threadX.interrupt()`.

It doesn't happen randomly - and any function that interrupts another thread will explicitly say so. (Mostly this is shutdown type functions on thread pools etc.)

Calls like `Thread.sleep()` watch for that call to `interrupt()` and respond by throwing an exception.

But if your thread doesn't call functions that watch for interruption by throwing `InteruptedException` - then you can watch for it using `Thread.isInterrupted()` (which is what the tutorial is about).

Here's an example of how you might use it. `threadX` is started and begins printing. The main thread (which starts `threadX` waits a little while then interrupts `threadX`, which will cause `Thread.sleep()` in `threadX` to throw an `InterruptedException` - `threadX` will then get a chance to print out its exit message.

```
   Thread threadX = new Thread( new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
       try {
       while(true) {
         Thread.sleep(100);
         System.err.println("In threadX");
       }
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         System.err.println("ThreadX interrupted and exiting...");
         // Restore the interrupted status 
         // not really needed here as we know the thread is exiting
         // but a good practice all the same. (So callers know 
         // we've been interrupted.)
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
       }
    }
  });

  threadX.start();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  threadX.interrupt();
```

It's worth noting that if your function handles `InterruptedException` and doesn't rethrow it, (and doesn't cause the thread to immediately exit) then you should restore the intterupted state (which will have been cleared by the thrower of the InterruptedException) This way any callers know the thread has been interrupted. (Conversely if you throw an `InterruptedException` because you found `inInterrupted()` to be true you should first clear the interrupted state)

Comment: Alright, thanks for finally giving me a good explanation :) My question now is, why use the exception if you could just use `Thread.isInterrupted()` to check and act upon the result? Could one just program without bothering with the exception and just use the method instead?

Comment: No you can't avoid using the `InterruptedException` if you call the functions that can throw it - especially as when they throw the `InterruptedException` they clear the state of `Thread.isInterrupted`. However you will want to use `Thread.isInterrupted()` if you dont regularly call out to such functions. (Definition of sufficiently regularly is up to the developer...)

Comment: @AaronFlores How do you check `isInterrupted` if you're blocked on an IO call?

Comment: Something like Thread.sleep() throws InterruptedException because otherwise there could be a very long delay before your code responds to the interruption.  The InterruptedException will be thrown immediately when the interrupt happens, instead of after the normal sleep time is over.

Comment: One of the most important things to know is that you should reset the interupted state whenever you catch an InterruptedException: `catch (InterruptedException e) { 
             // Restore the interrupted status
             Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
         }`

Comment: Aaah, I get it now.. it would've taken just two lines to explain this in the tutorial lol. But thanks to you all for your help :)

Comment: @Tony - You should restore the interupted status, unless you know the thread is going to immediately exit. So no need for that in the example. But you're right I'll add it to the body.

Comment: For the question,'My question now is, why use the exception if you could just use Thread.isInterrupted() to check and act upon the result?' Sometimes, your code is not the owner of the thread, e.g when you use a thread pool, there is no chance for you to call Thread.interupe(). The only think you can do is to handle the InterruptedException in your code

Answer (score 3):

You say:

> they don't explain what causes the interrupt exception to be thrown, or how, or what it even is.. they just say it can happen whenever you invoke certain methods like Thread.sleep()

Thread interrupts happen when the `interrupt()` method of the Thread is called.

The reference to `Thread.sleep()` is in relation to *handling* the interrupt, not raising it. Some methods, such as `Thread.sleep()` throw `InterruptedException`, which gives you the programmer a chance to deal with the interrupt in whatever way you like.

If the thread never or rarely calls a method that throws `InterruptedException` then you can check the interrupted status of a thread by invoking `Thread.interrupted()`, and if true, take the appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

An interrupt comes from another thread.  Like many other concurrent behaviors, it is "random" in that it MAY or MAY NOT happen during any particular method invocation, however it is not just a random thing that java sometimes does.  Interrupts come from things like a user closing the application, or possibly in response to some nasty error condition where the application needs to shutdown.  You can't know in advance whether this will happen during a particular method call, so you have to code against the possibility that it might happen.

Comment: Are you sure those things give the Thread a chance to handle `isInterrupted()`, or generate `InterruptionException`s? I thought `kill -9` and `System.exit()` would kill the application without any of those occurring.

Comment: That's why `kill -9 <PID>` should be a last resort - it doesn't allow code to cleanly exit.  `kill <PID>` Sends an interrupt that code can handle.  Somewhat off topic from your specific question, but good material on HOW to handle interupts can be found at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976344/handling-interruptedexception-in-java

Comment: Signals don't cause interrupts, only interrupting a thread with Thread.interrupt() does.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, didn't know that, thanks for the clarification.  Apparently you use Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(...) to handle signals.