# Java - concurrency: LinkedBlockingQueue, "try again if failed"

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, queue

```
int capacity = ...
BlockingQueue q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Element>(capacity);
```

Now, I do feel mildly ridiculous asking this but I'm not particularly savvy when it comes to java concurrency, so I would appreciate some help with choosing the correct way to enqueue something (and dequeue, actually, but I expect when we cleared up the one, the other will fall into place by itself).

There is, of course

```
while(!q.offer(e));
```

But I'm a bit wary of spinning implementations in a multi-threaded environment.

And I can't do

```
synchronized(q){
    while(!q.offer(e))q.wait();
}
```

either because the wakeup calls will go to internal (private) instances of `Condition`, meaning this would be a suicide-by-sleeping-pills implementation.

However, I'm also not particularly fond of

```
try{
    q.put(e);
}catch(InterruptedException ex){}
```

(even though it *does* seem to be a popular choice in online examples) because although this would do the waiting for me, I know of no reliable way to detect when an exception would force me to try again.
I could do something like

```
boolean success = false;
do{
    try{
        q.put(e);
        success = true;
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){}
}while(!success)
```

But then I'd end up enqueuing the same element multiple times if the exception takes place in-between the `put` and the assignment to `success`.

I could do

```
boolean success = true;
do{
    try{
        q.put(e);
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){
        success = false;
    }
}while(!success)
```

But I remember having read (way back) that you shouldn't rely on exception handling for conditionals (though I can't seem to remember the reason why this is discouraged).

So ... what options do I have? Do I need to spin or is there something more intelligent?

Comment: What do you think Blocking Queue by name means? Why would you need synchronized over it?

Comment: @SMA because the point in that snippet is to get the thread waiting and ``offer`` does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good practice to catch an `InterruptedException` as you do since your code won't be responsive to interruption anymore. An `InterruptedException` is usually thrown by methods that are responsive to interruptions (current `Thread` being interrupted) such as the methods of type `await`, `wait`, `join`, `sleep` and many others, this should not be considered as a failure but rather as it really is, a `Thread`'s status change that needs be taken into consideration.

As **Brian Goetz** explains in `Java Concurrency in Practice`, I quote:

> When your code calls a method that throws `InterruptedException`, then
>   your method is a blocking method too, and must have a plan for
>   responding to interruption. For library code, there are basically two
>   choices:
>
> **Propagate the InterruptedException.** This is often the most sensible policy if you can get away with it just propagate the
>   `InterruptedException` to your caller. This could involve not catching
>   `InterruptedException`, or catching it and throwing it again after
>   performing some brief activity-specific cleanup.
>
> **Restore the interrupt.** Sometimes you cannot throw `InterruptedException`, for instance when your code is part of a
>   `Runnable`. In these situations, you must catch `InterruptedException`
>   and restore the interrupted status by calling `interrupt` on the
>   current thread, so that code higher up the call stack can see that an
>   interrupt was issued.

So in your case, you should simply use `put(E)` as it will make the calling thread waits for space to become available if needed and **propagate the `InterruptedException`** in order to keep on being responsive to interruptions.

---

> But then I'd end up enqueuing the same element multiple times if the
>   exception takes place in-between the `put` and the assignment to
>   `success`.

This can simply **never** happen since an assignment of a `boolean` will **never** throw any exceptions (except a NPE in case of an un-boxing). And only methods responsive to interruption can throw such kind of exceptions as explained above which is clearly not the case of an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The `put()` implementation would be the correct one, blocking until interrupted or successful. The `offer()` is a bad idea if all you are doing is spinning (see first comment for disclaimer).

As Nicolas explained, the handling of the `InterruptedException` is not straightforward and depends a lot on what your other code is doing, but your concern with "if the exception takes place in-between the put and the assignment to success", that can never happen: a blocking call (like `put()`) can throw that exception, but it cannot occur between `put()` and the assignment, or at the assignment.

Lastly, there's no need to synchronize on anything. The main idea in many of `java.util.concurrent` classes is to avoid or abstract away the explicit synchronization.

Comment: Spinning on `offer` is not a bad idea in all cases.  If you're after a high-throughput system, then it may be bitter to spin briefly than give up control of the processor by blocking.  But that's a minor point that's applicable in only a tiny handful of use cases.

Comment: @JoeC Indeed, a rarer use case.

Comment: Spurious interrupt? Aren't you confusing this with spurious wakeups?

Comment: @bowmore Good catch. Shouldn't do SO while tired.

Answer (score 0):

So a few points from the [LinkedBlockingQueue Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html):

- The `put` method will only throw exceptions in two circumstances:

  - The thread is interrupted, in which case you should stop whatever you're doing anyway.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976344/handling-interruptedexception-in-java) for more about `InterruptedException`s.
  - The element you're inserting is `null`, which is another bug entirely.

So overall, you can just use `put` to wait for space to become available.  If either of these particular exceptions is thrown, then you shouldn't retry anyway.

Comment: A spurious interrupt should usually be ignored, instead of stopping everything.