# Use the run method to start a watcher Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, state

I have a

```
 ThreadPoolExecutor cachedPool = (ThreadPoolExecutor)Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

The `cachededPool` has to perform the following functionality in the main `SimController` class.

Run method for a watcher thread. Once per Second, check and call a function.

```
public void run(){
            if(m.isChanged()){
                m.toString();
            }                   
    }
```

But it only executes the run method once.
How can I make it run every second and create a watcher.

Comment: You need to use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit- on a ScheduledExecutorService.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `m.toString();` expression? Why is the value of the expression ignored?

Comment: Its an object of a MemManager class. It displays the state of memory in a specific format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()` as suggested by Peter Lawrey in a comment, or you can do the following:

```
public void run() throws InterruptedException {
    for( ;; ) {
        if( m.isChanged() ) //hopefully m is thread-safe
            m.toString();   //hopefully something more meaningful here
        Thread.sleep( 1000 ); //1000 milliseconds is one second.
    }
}
```

Note: if your `run()` method cannot throw `InterruptedException`, then you need to handle the `InterruptedException` that may be thrown by `Thread.sleep()`.  A quick and dirty way to do this is to just say `try{ ... } catch( InterruptedException e ) { throw new AssertionError( e ); }` but if you want to do it the proper way, then be sure to read this: [Handling InterruptedException in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976344/handling-interruptedexception-in-java)

Comment: I know this is sample code @mike but in case you care, `run()` doesn't throw exceptions.

Comment: @Gray thanks.  I wanted to avoid having to explain how to handle `InterruptedException`.  I settled for an interim solution which simply points to another answer.

Comment: There's a possible down-side to this suggestion: It dedicates an entire thread to mostly sitting around waiting, doing nothing.  I've written lots of threads that do pretty much the same thing, but it might be undesirable on a high-performance system that pushes the limits of the available hardware.

Comment: @jameslarge you are right.  But I suspect that this is waaaay beyond the concerns of the OP.  C-:=

Comment: People use `InterruptedException` so poorly that I make sure I _do_ explain it every time @Mike.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The ScheduledExecutorService makes this pretty simple as this example, which prints the date every second, shows:

```
public class MonitorService {
    public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
        ScheduledExecutorService service = 
                Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

If you have multiple jobs to schedule in your system you would want to share the scheduled executor service among all tasks for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring then you could also use @Scheduled task over a method to run a scheduled task.

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class TestClass {
    @Scheduled(fixedRate= 1000 , initialDelay = 18000)
    public void TestMethod(){
       // Do Something

    } }
```