# Either re-interrupt this method or rethrow the "InterruptedException issue in sonar

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throws, interrupted-exception

In one of my method, interrupted exception and execution exception is coming.
I put in try catch like this.

```
try{

  //my code
}catch(InterruptedException|ExecutionException e)

  Log.error(" logging it");
  throw new MonitoringException("it failed" , e)


//monitoringexception extends RunTimeException
```

Also in my method I put throws `InterruptedException,ExecutionException`

I am getting below critical error in sonar -  Either re-interrupt this method or rethrow the "`InterruptedException`"

Anyone know how to fix this.

Please help immediately.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976344/handling-interruptedexception-in-java

Answer (score 81):

To "re-interrupt" as a best practice:

```
try{
    //some code
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    logger.error("InterruptedException: ", ie);
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
} catch (ExecutionException ee) {
    logger.error("ExecutionException: ",ee);
}
```

Usually, when a thread is interrupted, whoever is interrupting the thread, wants the thread to exit what it's currently doing.

However, make sure that you do **NOT** multi-catch:

```
catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {     
  logger.error("An error has occurred: ", e);
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

We do not want ExecutionException to be "re-interrupted".

**BONUS:**
If you are interested, you can play with the examples [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-a-thread-can-interrupt-an-another-thread-in-java/)


Cheers

Comment: Weird my vscode says that the second catch is unrechable code.

Comment: Instead of re-interrupt, why shouldn't we call interrupted() so that the flag is cleared?
Also my doubt is, it has come to catch block,because someone has tried interrupting the thread,so what is the point in interrupting it?