# Handling ClosedByInterruptException in Java

Tags: java, exception, nio

There is a lot of [detailed advice about handling `InterruptedException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976344/handling-interruptedexception-in-java) properly. Do any of the same principles apply to handling [`ClosedChannelException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ClosedChannelException.html) from NIO calls, which can be a [`ClosedByInterruptException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ClosedByInterruptException.html)? In particular, when catching a CBIE, should `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what the documentation of [`ClosedByInterruptException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/ClosedByInterruptException.html) says (**emphasis** mine):

> Checked exception received by a thread when another thread interrupts it while it is blocked in an I/O operation upon a channel. **Before this exception is thrown the channel will have been closed and the interrupt status of the previously-blocked thread will have been set.**

Also, the `ClosedByInterruptException` class and its superclass, `AsynchronousCloseException`, are associated with channels which implement [`InterruptibleChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html). The documentation of that interface says (**emphasis** mine):

> A channel that can be asynchronously closed and interrupted.
>
> A channel that implements this interface is *asynchronously closeable:* If a thread is blocked in an I/O operation on an interruptible channel then another thread may invoke the channel's `close` method. This will cause the blocked thread to receive an `AsynchronousCloseException`.
>
> **A channel that implements this interface is also *interruptible:* If a thread is blocked in an I/O operation on an interruptible channel then another thread may invoke the blocked thread's `interrupt` method. This will cause the channel to be closed, the blocked thread to receive a `ClosedByInterruptException`, and the blocked thread's interrupt status to be set.**
>
> **If a thread's interrupt status is already set and it invokes a blocking I/O operation upon a channel then the channel will be closed and the thread will immediately receive a `ClosedByInterruptException`; its interrupt status will remain set.**
>
> A channel supports asynchronous closing and interruption if, and only if, it implements this interface. This can be tested at runtime, if necessary, via the `instanceof` operator.

In other words, you do not need to call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` after catching a `ClosedByInterruptException` because the channel will have already set, or simply maintained, the interrupt status of the thread. I suspect this behavior is specified especially to avoid forcing developers having to re-interrupt the thread, unlike when catching an `InterruptedException`.