# InterruptedException, API design and leaky abstractions

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, api-design, interrupted-exception

[It's well agreed that `InterruptedException` should not be swallowed in general](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976377/28190); it is a request that a thread cleanup and terminate its work.

How should the API design of a given abstraction `I` handle `InterruptedException` if a subset of its implementations may throw `InterruptedException`?

More concretely, imagine a `Datasource` with `InMemoryDatasource` and `NetworkDatasource` implementations. The latter includes a blocking call over a network, and thus may throw `InterruptedException`. This means `InterruptedException` should be declared on the `Datasource` interface.

This seems appropriate - it's a data source, you don't know where the data is coming from, so it *might* block and clients should handle `InterruptedException` as a result.

But it brings something else to mind - **why don't we see *more* `InterruptedException`s being declared in APIs?**

For example:

- The JDBC API doesn't declare it, even though it makes blocking calls.
- [The PostgreSQL JDBC driver swallows such exceptions and rethrows them as `SQLException`s.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/F6FBC511-F1BA-4ED7-B0E1-F3EB702A3077%40spontech-spine.com).
- [It looks like the MongoDB driver wraps it in a RuntimeException.](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoInterruptedException.html)
- [The AWS SDK doesn't throw it (but at least sets the interrupted flag).](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/276)

It seems *general* to not rethrow `InterruptedException` in APIs.

As an API designer, how is it best to deal with `InterruptedException`?