# OkHttpClient with Java Future java.io.InterruptedIOException

Tags: java, okhttp

I am trying to make a web scraper that parses specific URL indefinitely with some delay in between.
I have a method `genericMonitor` that accepts the url to parse and a callback to return a result.
This method is called repeatedly using `SheduledExecutorService`. The code is below:

```
ScheduledFuture<?> task = service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
          try {
            genericMonitor(percent, url, idSupplier, callback);
          } catch (IOException connectException) {
            logger.error("Error in generic", connectException);
          }
        }, 0, delay, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        tasks.put(link, task);
```

The `tasks` map holds all currently running tasks.
I make http requests using `OkHttp` Java library.
When I try to cancel the task using `task.cancel` I get `InterruptedIOException`:

```
java.io.InterruptedIOException: interrupted
    at okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:146)
    at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:76)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:180)
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:179)
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.writeByte(RealBufferedSink.java:125)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Writer.writeMedium(Http2Writer.java:265)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Writer.frameHeader(Http2Writer.java:253)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Writer.headers(Http2Writer.java:289)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection.newStream(Http2Connection.java:253)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection.newStream(Http2Connection.java:225)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec.writeRequestHeaders(Http2Codec.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:54)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:264)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:93)
    at org.dk.Bot.callRemoteWithProxy(Bot.java:82)
    at org.dk.Bot.genericMonitor(Bot.java:182)
    at org.dk.Bot.lambda$processCommand$1(Bot.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

I am not sure what's the problem

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown when you call [`cancel`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) with parameter `mayInterruptIfRunning` set to true.

> ...
> If the task has already started, then the **mayInterruptIfRunning** parameter determines whether the thread executing this task should be interrupted in an attempt to stop the task.
> ...
>
> Parameters:
> mayInterruptIfRunning - true if the thread executing this task should be interrupted; otherwise, in-progress tasks are allowed to complete

Hence it will interrupt the task and cause `InterruptedIOException` inside your running task. If you want to allow in-progress task to complete, call `cancel(false)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all the answers. I realised calling the `cancel` is not canceling the execution itself. It only sets the flag. You would need to check inside the task itself whether the thread is interrupted and handle accordingly. In my case I just returned from the method.

Answer (score 0):

**From Oracle documentation** of the class **InterruptedIOException** :

- Signals that an I/O operation has been interrupted. An
- `InterruptedIOException` is thrown to indicate that an
- input or output transfer has been terminated because the thread
- performing it was interrupted. The field {@link #bytesTransferred}
- indicates how many bytes were successfully transferred before
- the interruption occurred.

You are trying to cancel or interrup a thread who execute an IO operation , i think in the method "genericMonitor" you have some IO operations , or you are trying to interrupt the thread when he is in the catch block writing in the log file , so that's why you got this type of exception.

You can add isDone before calling cancel to be sure that the exception will not be thrown .
or you can handle this Exception and be sure that all of your ressources are closed ( try with ressources) , this link give you an idea about how to handle a similar exception type : [Handling InterruptedException in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976344/handling-interruptedexception-in-java)  .

You can use also :    boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning);
Try to read the documentation of this method and see if it can help you .