# Correct Handling of `InterruptedExceptions` in Java

Tags: java, sonarqube, future, sonarlint, interrupted-exception

So, I am having an issue where Sonar Qube is flagging my code due to improper handling of `InterruptedExceptions`. The exact Sonar Qube error is `java:S2142`, and can be found here: https://github.com/joansmith/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/resources/org/sonar/l10n/java/rules/squid/S2142.html

My code is below - Sonar Qube is flagging the handling of possible `InterruptedExceptions` in `extractFutureIntoList()` as the source of the problem:

```java
@Service
@Log4j2
public class AsynchronousDataGrabber {

  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

  public List<MyDataObject> getDataAsynchronously() {
    Optional<Future<MyDataObject>> future01 = getDataFuture("01");
    Optional<Future<MyDataObject>> future02 = getDataFuture("02");
    Optional<Future<MyDataObject>> future03 = getDataFuture("03");

    List<MyDataObject> list = new ArrayList();
    
    extractFutureIntoList(future01, list);
    extractFutureIntoList(future02, list);
    extractFutureIntoList(future03, list);
    
    return list;
  }


  private Optional<Future<MyDataObject>> getDataFuture(String key) {
    try {
      return Optional.of(executorService.submit(() -> getDataFromRemoteApi(key)));
    } catch(Exception e) {
      log.error("Exception", e);
      return Optional.empty();
    }
  }
  
  private void extractFutureIntoList(Optional<Future<MyDataObject>> future, List<MyDataObject> list) {
    try {
      if (future.isPresent()) {  
        // This is apparently where the `InterruptedException` can occur - Future.get()
    list.add(future.get().get());  
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // SonarQube is telling me that merely logging an `InterupptedException` is not enough
      // Apparently, I must either rethrow the `InterruptedException`,
      //or call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()
      log.error("Exception", e);
      return;   
    }
  }
}
```

Sonar Qube proposes that I solve this problem either by rethrowing `InterruptedException`, or by calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` -- whenever `Future.get()` is interrupted.

My problem with this is that `getDataAsynchronously()` is being called by my application's main thread. If the only acceptable response to an `InterruptedException` is to rethrow it or interrupt the current thread, then a single interrupt in one of my `executorService's` threads will bring down my entire application. This seems to be an excessive response, especially given that the task being run by the threads - `getDataFromRemoteApi()` - may not always be successful anyway.

Is there a better way to handle `InterruptedException` - ideally one that is acceptable to Sonar Qube, but doesn't involve killing the thread that is trying to call `Future.get()`?

I have tried logging the `InterruptedException` (`log.error("Exception", e);`), and I have tried to catch and rethrow the `InterruptedException` (`throw new RuntimeException(e);`) - neither appeased Sonar Qube.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling InterruptedException in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976344/handling-interruptedexception-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never ignore `InterruptedException` indeed.

Risen `InterruptedException` means running thread was marked as interrupted, that signal (could be checked with `Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()`) was received and **removed**. So catching it without throwing up/calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` leads to forgetting the fact of interruption forever.

If you have caught an `InterruptedException` do graceful return from the method and throw exception up or recover the flag and return.

In your particular case getting an `InterruptedException` in the specified line means your **main** thread has been interrupted (not an executor's). It means somebody stopped the program, thus is not interested in method return value anymore. I suggest you either:

1. Call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` and then `throw new RuntimeException(e)`. That's okey - you both keep the flag of interruption and indicate that your `getDataAsynchronously()` hasn't been executed correctly and there is no answer to return.
2. Do "best effort" - call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` and just return from `extractFutureIntoList`. Your program would continue executing `extractFutureIntoList` calls left. If any of other futures would be already complete, thus their result is available immediately, `future.get()` would return calculation result without throwing `InterruptedException`. So you would collect data from all futures done at the moment of thread interruption. It would be a kind of graceful shutdown.
3. If possible - mark `getDataAsynchronously` as `throws InterruptedException` and re-throw exception. It's a best practice - mark any blocking method as `throws InterruptedException`. Your method `getDataAsynchronously` is blocking and actually implies to throw it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I guess I am struggling to understand where interrupts come from, and why they are so significant that we would want to let the main thread die if one occurs. What are the conditions under which I might receive an interrupt, and what exactly is a consequence of simply ignoring an interrupt and proceeding on as if nothing happened?

Comment: Finally interrupts are occurred due to thread.interrupt() call. A call could be done manually in your code, or indirectly for example, under the hood of framework on shutdown, or by calling ExecutorService.shutdownNow(), or Future.cancel(true), etc.

Comment: Consequence of ignoring interruption is interruption not working ;) What does it lead to? It depends. It could be for example a resources leak (memory, threads), program hangup, not working buttons/calls.

Comment: Thanks also from me. The method `java.net.http.HttpClient#send` has `InterruptedException` in its signature since Java 16/17. So this issue will probably be raised more often in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The catching of an `InterruptedException` also clears the interrupted status of the thread. If you decide to eat the `InterruptedException`, then in all cases I can think of you should call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` to re-mark the thread as interrupted, so that any other call on that thread to `Thread.isInterrupted()` will report that an interrupt occurred.  The other viable alternative (which SonarQube suggests) is to change various method signatures to declare that `InterruptedException` can be thrown, and then don't catch the exception.  Both of these approaches ensure that the fact that the thread was interrupted at some point is available to interested parties.

In almost all cases I can think of where you can't adjust method signatures, the first option is exactly what you want to do.

It sounds like for whatever (perhaps valid) reason maybe you don't want to do this, so assuming that your case is valid, I suppose you could just (as SonarQube suggests) simply log the exception without resetting the original interrupted status of the thread, but just be aware that you're losing information in this case (everything will look to other parties as if an interrupt never occurred).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I choose simply to log the exception and continue, what is the significance of losing that interrupted status? Does clearing an interrupted status and continuing have any downstream consequences?

Comment: I want to speak carefully because I don't actually recommend ignoring the interrupt status. I think maybe you think that calling `interrupt()` will itself do something bad to your application (maybe you think it itself will throw something? it will not), but if I'm reading your code right I fail to see how. To answer: there should be no downstream consequences apart from losing the visible effect that an interrupt ever happened. See also: Java Concurrency In Practice which has a section on this.