# Why is re-interrupting the right practise of handling the InterruptedException instead of calling interrupted()?

Tags: java, multithreading

Instead of re-interrupt, why shouldn't we call interrupted() so that the flag is cleared.
I heard the flag is set when interrupt() is called(lets say by jvm) and then the InterruptedException is thrown,so
someone has tried interrupting the thread,so what is the point in re-interrupting it?
Instead if we call interrupted() it would clear the flag of that thread ,it makes more sense right like

```
if (Thread.interrupted()) {
    throw new InterruptedException();
}
```

Comment: What if some other parts of the code is relying on that interrupted flag to terminate gracefully and does not expect you to clear that flag and throw an InterruptedException?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling InterruptedException in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976344/handling-interruptedexception-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

> Why is re-interrupting the right practise of handling the InterruptedException instead of calling interrupted()?

First of all, when `InterruptedException` is thrown, the interrupt bit on the thread is cleared so there is nothing for you to do to *clear* it.

But, it is standard practice to *re-interrupt* the thread when you catch `InterruptedException`.  Why?  Because you don't want a method or a library clearing the interrupt bit and then returning to the caller without somehow informing the caller that an interrupt has happened.

The correct pattern is something like:

```
try {
   ...
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
   // re-interrupt the thread now that the interrupt flag has been cleared
   Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   // deal with the interrupt like stopping the job or returning or ...
}
```

For a specific example, the caller might have a look like this:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    // this method better not clear the interrupted flag on the thread!
    callSomeMethod();
}
```

If the `callSomeMethod()` used `Thread.sleep()` or other methods that throw `InterruptedException` and swallowed the interrupt flag and returned, then the while loop would never terminate.